# Nightwatch.js custom command this vs this.api

Tags: nightwatch.js

```
// myCustomCommand.js
module.exports = function () {
  this.SOME_NIGHTWATCH_COMMAND(...) // fails, undefined
  this.api.SOME_NIGHTWATCH_COMMAND(...) // works
}
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports.command = ...` instead of `module.exports = ...`